# View Workflow history list

Tags: workflow, workflow-history, log

This probably has a simple solution but I can't figure it out. I have an approval based workflow and I want to be able to view the results/status of the approvals.

I assigned a task for a user to approve a task:

Start a task process with BOB(`Task outcome to Variable: Outcome3` )

`Log Variable: Outcome3 to the workflow history list`

and I want to see their approval. Any idea of where I can view this or what I need to create to be able to keep a record of these approvals?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Their approval is, basically, in two places. One is the task list, which is the easiest way for you to find a task and see its result.

From within the item, you can view the workflow history... the tasks and their outcomes should be in there also. By default, the workflow history found through the item will be removed after 60 days.

However, this information will still be in the Workflow History list: http://sharepoint/mysite/lists/Workflow%20History/AllItems.aspx. You can filter this list by the list GUID to see just items from the list you're working on.

Comment: Does this work for Sharepoint Online?

Answer (score 2):

To view the status just follow the below steps:-

1. Open your site through SharePoint Designer and navigate to the workflow you must have created.
2. Open the workflow(by clicking on it).
3. Look at the list you have created to store history and task.
4. Navigate to that list you can see the status of all items.